# Comparing two rows each from two tables in MySQL, displaying only negative results

Tags: mysql, compare, multiple-tables

So I've got a table called "HoldingQueue" and I want to compare two rows to two values and return every row that doesn't match BOTH of those values. Here's an example of the content:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * *
* ItemCode * Channel  *
* * * * * * * * * * * *
* 1PX1     * Test     *
* * * * * * * * * * * *
* 2PX1     * Test     *
* * * * * * * * * * * *
* 3PX1     * Test2    *
* * * * * * * * * * * *
```

And the query:

```
SELECT * FROM HoldingQueue WHERE ItemCode<>"1PX1" AND Channel<>"Test";
```

This is returning ONLY "3PX1 | Test2" - where I want it to be returning everything that isn't "1PX1 | Test" - so "2PX1 | Test" should also be returning.

Any ideas? Kinda banging my head against a wall here.

Edit: Alright, so it's working with the small data set using OR... but I just realized the issue I'm having. I'm attempting to pull the "ItemCode" and "Channel" to compare it to from another table that has multiple entries, but I'm realizing now that because there are MULTIPLE entries on that table, EVERYTHING qualifies at least once as having neither of the set of values.

I think my question is more complicated than this.

**Edit #2: Got it...**

```
SELECT Channel, ItemCode FROM HoldingQueue H
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM SKUList S
    WHERE
        H.ItemCode=S.SKU
        AND
        H.Channel=S.Channel
) GROUP BY H.Channel,H.ItemCode;
```

I wanted any items that don't match WITH ANYTHING from the second SKUList table. This did it. Will mark Sergey Kudriavtsev the answer because he did correctly answer my initial question (that left out much of the problem I was facing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `AND` to `OR` in your query, so it will be

```
SELECT * FROM HoldingQueue WHERE ItemCode<>"1PX1" OR Channel<>"Test";
```

Comment: Well, that does appear to work with the small sample, but not the larger data set I'm trying to get it working with. I'll update my main post.